# Salesforce Integration with Google calendar

Tags: integration, salesforce-id, google

I have a requirement to create a Google calendar event as soon as an event in SF is created. I see few google APIs but these does not seem to be free. Are these any free API or products for the same.

Comment: I just did this the other day using a SFDC calendar synced to a Google Calendar via Ebsta (first three users are free). Otherwise, I think you are writing to the Google API either via Javascript or apex

Answer (score 1):

Refer to below link...this  will solve your problem.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

I am using google calender api in my project and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try considering Google's Calendar API v3 (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar).

Google Developers Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) allows to to play around with this api as well. Let me know how you go.